# Selecting Outer Row for Subtable MS Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

For MS Word tables/vba:

I have a sub-table within a row. When the cursor is placed in the sub-table, I'd like to select the outer table's row. I can't seem to find a way to select the outer row. Your assistance is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please take a moment to read in the [help] about how to effectively ask questions on Stack Overflow. This is not free code-writing service or a tutorial site. You're expected to have done basic research and ask very specific questions about code you have.

Comment: Cindy, my apologies.  Will do. - Aaron

Answer (score 0):

The method isn't especially obvious:

```
Selection.Tables(1).Range.Characters.Last.Next.Cells(1).Row.Select
```